# Android license status unknown. Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-sdk-manager

My app were running absolutely fine before and I do not get what was the problem later on. There were no updates in any files. I got an error in D:\src-flutter\Flutter-Projects\testing_app\android\app\build.gradle file. I tried solving it using many links.

---

Here is the command line implementation: \

```
D:\src-flutter\flutter>flutter --version
Flutter 1.17.5 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 8af6b2f038 (8 days ago) • 2020-06-30 12:53:55 -0700
Engine • revision ee76268252
Tools • Dart 2.8.4

D:\src-flutter\flutter>java -version
java version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13, mixed mode)

D:\src-flutter\flutter>flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.900], locale en-IN)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit visit
      https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions.
[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Typing flutter doctor --android-licenses does not work.

```
D:\src-flutter\flutter>flutter doctor --android-licenses
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 5 more
```

Hiding the obsolete packages does not give me an option of Android SDK tools.
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Caused by: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`

Verify the specified class name and check whether or not the `.jar` file exists in the classpath. If it already exists, then make sure that it is not overridden in your program. If the file does not​ exist, then simply add the `.jar` file in the classpath.